# Spring scheduler is running twice

Tags: spring

I have read a few posts on these issues but it did not fix the problem.

```java
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class NotificationScheduled {
  @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * ?")
  public void email() {}
}
```

I tried adding `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` in the application property file but did not work.

I also read https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled section 25.5.1

I am running scheduler for every 5 min. When scheduler is kicked of (5 is up), it calls the method twice right away. Please help as I am running out of options. Thank you

As soon as I start tomcat (8.5), I see two scheduling thread. Could it tomcat?
[image]

UPDATE - I was able to fix the by removing the following line from tomcat config/server.xml. This line was deploying my app twice. I was able to see that from tocat manager.
<Context docBase="myapp path="/myapp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myapp"/>

Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: After how much time it run 2nd time?

Comment: You cron expression is indicating to fire every 5 min. What's your desired outcome?

Comment: it calls second method right after the 1st one.

Comment: Are you in any way programmatically registering multiple `NotificationScheduled` beans?

Comment: I check and I am not. As soon as I start tomcat, I am seeing  two scheduling thread. Could it tomcat?

Comment: Wait, those are not two scheduling threads. It is exactly the same thread (mind the name `scheduling-1`). Can you add some logs to the `public void email() {}` method to check if it is actually called twice? Or did you do that already?

Comment: @Meera, add your update as an answer and accept it so that your question can be closed ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the by removing the following line from tomcat config/server.xml. This line was deploying my app twice. I was able to see that from tocat manager. <Context docBase="myapp path="/myapp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myapp"/>

Thank you all for your inputs.